# ios: Creating a CoreData object without immediately persisting it

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence

I'm getting some data from the internet and want to store this data in an object, say "InternetData". This class holds some properties and also this class is bound to a core data persistence store.

I've already downloaded InternetData from previous session of my app and they are already stored in the database to which core data maps the objects. The problem: If I want to download new Internetdata now, I will download at least partially the same only a fraction of the new Internetdata that comes in is truely new the rest is already stored in my database. And I want to avoid that I will store the same data twice or more often.

Therefore, I want to create an empty instance of InternetData with [[InternetData alloc] init] write the stuff I've downloaded into that object and after that I want to use a comparison method that compares the unbound new InternetData object with the old one from the database. Only I the new object is not found in the old data I want to add the new object to the persistence store an eventually store it to the database. The problem I currently have is that my program crashes when I try to create an new InternetData object which is independent of the persitence sotre, I mean when doing [[InternetData alloc] init] I get the error message

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'InternetData'
>      [InternetData setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd26f4f0

So my question: Is this what I want basically possible to create an object of InternetData that is at first not bound to the core data persistence store and after a short period I would copy the newly created data into a second bounded InternetData object (which I created in a bounded manner) and then store it to the persistence store?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to resolve your problem. First of all you couldn't alloc+init instance of `NSManagedObjectModel`. So you can do of the following to store temporary data:

1. Store it in `NSDictionary`
2. Store it in another one `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using another NSManagedObjectContext seems a bit exaggerated in my case and therefore I would like to not use this approach. But I currently do not see how a NSDictionary would help in my case because as I see it I would have to create an empty instance of InternetData anyway which would again lead to the same error.

Comment: You can save all keys and values in dictionary. For example, object `InternetData` has property `data`. The you can store in dictionary: key==`data` and value for that key will store that data.

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible but only in a nice way applicable if I had just one new data package of InternetData each time. In fact I normally have maybee 2 or even 20 new packages which would ending up in doing something like date_key1==date1, text_key1==text1, date_key2==date2, text_key2==text2 and so on. In that case another maybee in memory based data store would be more appropriate, or I create a new helper class which would be the same as the originally class but not bound to any data store and it would be an equally as ugly solution. But anyway, thanks for your help.